# Module not found error even after installing watchdog package in ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: python, linux, watchdog

I install watchdog package `sudo apt-get install watchdog`.
I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
watchdog is already the newest version (5.14-3ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 485 not upgraded.
```

When I import watchdog after calling python, I got `ImportError: No module named 'watchdog'`

May I know how can I solve this issue in linux?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the software package that you want to install? Ubuntu also has a `python-watchdog`/`python3-watchdog` package.

Comment: In general you should keep your system updated. The OS version as well as 485 packages are out of date.

Comment: I don't find watchdog package after checking with ```apt list --installed```.
May I know how can I install ubuntu's ```python-watchdog```?

Comment: Hello @Klaus D,
I already upgraded packages using ```sudo apt-get update``` and I got the following messages: 

Fetched 297 kB in 58s (5,092 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied)

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/sg.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/sg.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Some index files failed to download.

Comment: They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: This is something to address in a Ubuntu related community.